# exporting invalid picture

Tags: excel, vba

i am creating a userform where i can export chart form excel sheet to the userform, i am using the following code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
Dim Fname As String
Dim cchart As Chart
Set cchart = Sheets("Times").ChartObjects(1).Chart
Fname = "D:\Ba\temp.gif"
cchart.Export Filename:=Fname
Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
End Sub
```

it worked well first time and now sometimes it works and sometimes it sayes " invalid picture" and when i go to D:\Ba\temp.gif on my computer i found the image invalid also.

Comment: Have you tried to save it as jpg?

Comment: yes I tried but the same problem happend

Answer (score 0):

i found this code and it is working well:

```
Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
 Call ChangeChart("weekly")
End Sub
```

and

```
 Sub ChangeChart(ChartName As String)

    Dim CurrentChart As Chart
    Dim FName As String
    
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
    
    Set CurrentChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Times").ChartObjects(ChartName).Chart
    
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=FName, filtername:="GIF"
    
    showpanel.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)


End Sub
```

thanks for the one who did it.
Can i put the name of the site i have the code from or no?